# GroupBy with multiple groups level

Tags: c#, linq

I am using GroupBy create a hierarchical set of groups to use in multiple child grids.

This is the function that return products.json

```
var result = lProd.SelectMany(x => x.Caracteristiques.Distinct(), (parentObj, childnum) =>
                                                 new
                                                 {
                                                     parentObj,
                                                     childnum
                                                 })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.childnum.nom)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        group = x.Key,
                        valeursAndUids = x.Select(z => (z.childnum.valeur, z.parentObj.ProductUid)).OrderBy(q => q.valeur)
                    }).Where(sid => OrdredList.Any(si => si == sid.group))
                    .OrderBy(x => OrdredList.IndexOf(x.group));
```

products.json

```
[
    {
        "group": "coloris", // LEVEL 1
        "valeursAndUids": [
            {
                "Item1": "Beige",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "Beige",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "Venezia",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "Venezia",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group": "ref_commercial", // LEVEL 2
        "valeursAndUids": [
            {
                "Item1": "29245",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "29245",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "29245",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "29245",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "group": "Address", // LEVEL 3
        "valeursAndUids": [
            {
                "Item1": "172 B",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "172 B",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "1725 A",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
            },
            {
                "Item1": "1725 A",
                "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
            }
        ]
    }
    //....
]
```

How do I get a grouping of products that are grouped by `group value`?

Basically I want it to output like so:

```
coloris Beige // Level 1
    ref_commercial 29245 // Level 2
        Address 172B  // Level 3
            QB32-20220325-486274
            QB32-20220325-106045
            ...
coloris Venezia
    ref_commercial 29245
        Address 1725 A
          QB32-20220325-205994
          QB32-20220325-270903
          ...
coloris N
    ref_commercial N
        Address N
             // Level N
                ...
```

This way I regrouped all the values by group/sub groups by respecting the level ( the group is already sorted so)
I can have many levels, but always I want to depend on the group value.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by defining a simple representation of a resulting grouping. The simplest I can think of is:

```csharp
// Resulting grouping
{
    Levels: { <level1>, <level2>, ... },
    Uids:   { <uidA>, <uidB>, ... }
}
```

Based on your example output, the resulting groupings could be represented as follows:

```csharp
// Resulting example groupings
{
    Levels: { ( "coloris", "Beige" ), ( "ref_commercial", "29245" ), ( "Address", "172 B" ) }
    Uids:   { "QB32-20220325-486274", "QB32-20220325-106045" }
},
{
    Levels: { ( "coloris", "Venezia" ), ( "ref_commercial", "29245" ), ( "Address", "1725 A" ) }
    Uids:   { "QB32-20220325-205994", "QB32-20220325-270903" }
}
```

Based on these groupings, one could either build a tree (where each resulting grouping would be a single branch), or simply display the nested grouping visually.

Either way, we first need to compute the resulting groupings. My approach uses the following logic:

1. Flatten each `group`/`Item1`/`Item2` value combination --> `( group, valeur, uid )`
2. Group the flattened items by `uid`

   - for each item in a group, keep only the `group` and `valeur` values
3. Group the items-by-uid groupings by matching `group/valeur` item collections
4. From each nested group, select the matching `group/valeur` item collection as the resulting grouping's `Levels`, and the collection of `uid` as the resulting grouping's `Uids`.

Assuming that the `Product` class looks as follows:

```csharp
public class Product
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public (string Item1, string Item2)[] ValeursAndUids { get; set; }
}
```

, the implementation could be:

```csharp
Product[] products = new[] { ... };

List<((string GroupName, string Valeur)[] Levels, string[] Uids)> groupings = products
    // Step 1:
    .SelectMany(p => p.ValeursAndUids
        .Select(vu => ( GroupName: p.Group, Valeur: vu.Item1, Uid: vu.Item2)))
    // Step 2:
    .GroupBy(item => item.Uid,
        item => ( item.GroupName, item.Valeur) )
    // Step 3:
    .GroupBy(itemsByUid => string.Join(string.Empty, itemsByUid.Select(_ => _)),
         // Step 4:
         (_, nestedGroup) => (
             Levels: nestedGroup.First().Select(level => level).ToArray(),
             Uids: nestedGroup.Select(itemsByUid => itemsByUid.Key).ToArray()
         ))
    .ToList();
```

Given your example input, this is pretty much how it will look after performing each step:

**Step 1** - flattening

```csharp
( "coloris", "Beige", "QB32-20220325-486274" )
( "coloris", "Beige", "QB32-20220325-106045" )
( "coloris", "Venezia", "QB32-20220325-205994" )
( "coloris", "Venezia", "QB32-20220325-270903" )
( "ref_commercial", "29245", "QB32-20220325-486274" )
( "ref_commercial", "29245", "QB32-20220325-106045" )
( "ref_commercial", "29245", "QB32-20220325-205994" )
( "ref_commercial", "29245", "QB32-20220325-270903" )
( "Address", "172 B", "QB32-20220325-486274" )
( "Address", "172 B", "QB32-20220325-106045" )
( "Address", "1725 A", "QB32-20220325-205994" )
( "Address", "1725 A", "QB32-20220325-270903" )
```

**Step 2** - grouping by `uid`; selecting only `group/valeur` values for each item

```csharp
"QB32-20220325-486274"
    ( "coloris", "Beige" )
    ( "ref_commercial", "29245" )
    ( "Address", "172B" )

"QB32-20220325-106045"
    ( "coloris", "Beige" )
    ( "ref_commercial", "29245" )
    ( "Address", "172B" )

"QB32-20220325-205994"
    ( "coloris", "Venezia" )
    ( "ref_commercial", "29245" )
    ( "Address", "1725 A" )

"QB32-20220325-270903"
    ( "coloris", "Venezia" )
    ( "ref_commercial", "29245" )
    ( "Address", "1725 A" )
```

Step 3 - grouping the groups by matching group/valeur item collections

```csharp
"(coloris, Beige)(ref_commercial, 29245)(Address, 172 B)"
    "QB32-20220325-486274"
        ("coloris", "Beige")
        ("ref_commercial", "29245")
        ("Address", "172 B")
    "QB32-20220325-106045"
        ("coloris", "Beige")
        ("ref_commercial", "29245")
        ("Address", "172 B")
"(coloris, Venezia)(ref_commercial, 29245)(Address, 1725 A)"
    "QB32-20220325-205994"
        ("coloris", "Venezia")
        ("ref_commercial", "29245")
        ("Address", "1725 A")
    "QB32-20220325-270903"
        ("coloris", "Venezia")
        ("ref_commercial", "29245")
        ("Address", "1725 A")
```

**Step 4** - selecting the appropriate `group/valeur` collection and `uid` collection for each nested group

```csharp
{
    Levels: { ( "coloris", "Beige" ), ( "ref_commercial", "29245" ), ( "Address", "172 B" ) }
    Uids:   { "QB32-20220325-486274", "QB32-20220325-106045" }
},
{
    Levels: { ( "coloris", "Venezia" ), ( "ref_commercial", "29245" ), ( "Address", "1725 A" ) }
    Uids:   { "QB32-20220325-205994", "QB32-20220325-270903" }
}
```

The nested grouping could then be visualized by e.g. the following level-wise printing:

```csharp
const string tab = "\t";
string tabs;

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    tabs = string.Empty;

    foreach (var level in group.Levels)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{tabs}{level.GroupName} {level.Valeur}");

        tabs += tab;
    }

    foreach (var uid in group.Uids)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{tabs}{uid}");
    }
}
```

, or be nested into a tree structure (not shown in this answer).

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7lADvR).

Comment: The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, int, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I think because it's a tuple ?

Comment: @Taieb That may be. Which .NET / .NET Framework and C# version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 5.0.0 version, your response is the closed one of the result I Want to get.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the error, just let me show you a screenshot

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/cwxB3hM_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand

Comment: I see. Does this work for you? [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0mTCvM). If it does, I will update my answer.

Comment: Astrid I'm going to update my question with the function that is returning the products.json so you can help if possible with my existing context

Comment: Please check my updated question with the function that return the result that I want to modify, thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Taieb I have tried to adjust my previous fiddle to fit the object structure you presented in your question update. If you replace line 28 in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2zSz6) with your own code for generating `result`, do you get what you need?

Comment: Thank you so much Astrid. 
Do you know a way to delete from the list of uids ? I'm facing a problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71773065/delete-value-from-list-inside-a-list-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

I have not come up with anything better than building a tree and printing it using the [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#:%7E:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%20and,structures%20without%20modifying%20the%20structures.) pattern.

First of all, we need to build a flat list of products:

```cs
// just collect all groups into a single list
// it will produce the list: ["coloris", "ref_commercial", "Address", ""]
List<string> groups = listProducts.Select(p => p.Group).ToList();
groups.Add(""); // group for uids

// build flat list of products
// each product will be represented as a list of group values:
// [ ["Beige", "29245", "172 B", "QB32-20220325-486274"], ["Beige", "29245", "172 B", "QB32-20220325-106045"],... ]
IEnumerable<List<string>> products = listProducts
    .SelectMany(product => product.ValeursAndUids, (product, valueAndUid) => new { product.Group, valueAndUid })
    .GroupBy(item => item.valueAndUid.Item2)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        List<string> path = g.Select(item => item.valueAndUid.Item1).ToList();
        path.Add(g.Key);
        return path;
    });
```

Now we can build a tree:

```cs
TreeNode root = new TreeNode("root", "");
TreeNode parent = root;
foreach (List<string> path in products)
{
    TreeNode current = parent;

    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
    {
        string part = path[i];
        parent = parent.GetChild(groups[i], part);
    }

    parent = current;
}
```

and print it:

```cs
root.Accept(new DepthTreeVisitor());
```

**Output**:

```
root
  coloris Beige
    ref_commercial 29245
      Address 172 B
         QB32-20220325-486274
         QB32-20220325-106045
  coloris Venezia
    ref_commercial 29245
      Address 1725 A
         QB32-20220325-205994
         QB32-20220325-270903
```

`TreeNode` and `Visitor` definitions:

```cs
public class TreeNode {

    public TreeNode(string groupName, string value)
    {
        GroupName = groupName;
        Value = value;
        Children = new HashSet<TreeNode>();
    }

    public string Value { get; }
    public string GroupName { get; }
    public ISet<TreeNode> Children { get; }

    public void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitTree(this);
    }

    public TreeNode GetChild(string group, string value)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode child in Children)
        {
            if (child.Value.Equals(value))
            {
                return child;
            }
        }

        return GetChild(new TreeNode(group, value));
    }

    private TreeNode GetChild(TreeNode child)
    {
        Children.Add(child);
        return child;
    }
}

public interface Visitor
{
    public void VisitTree(TreeNode tree);
}

public class DepthTreeVisitor : Visitor
{
    private int level = 0;

    public void VisitTree(TreeNode tree)
    {
        string indentString = new string(' ', 2 * level);
        Console.WriteLine($"{indentString}{tree.GroupName} {tree.Value}");
        level++;

        foreach (TreeNode child in tree.Children)
        {
            child.Accept(this);
        }

        level--;
    }
}
```

Here is complete [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/omAP0D).

Comment: Thank you for your response, is there a way to get the result as an Object so I can perform other functions on it, in the future ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to get the key and group name of the group, the iterate over the subgroups. Something like this should work:

```cs
public void GenerateGroups(List<Product> myList)
{
    var groups = myList.GroupBy(g => g.Group);

    foreach (var group in groups)
    { 
        var groupName = group.Key;
        var groupValue = group.First().Group;

        foreach (var group2 in group)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I setup a simple couple of classes to illustrate:

```cs
internal class Product
{
    public string? Group { get; set; }
    public List<ValeursAndUids>? ValeursAndUids { get; set; }
}

internal class ValeursAndUids
{
    public string? Item1 { get; set; }
    public string? Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Unfortunately the Group is not fixed, sometimes I Can have 3 sometimes i can have N.

Is there a way to transform the json I gave to the wanted result ?