# Anonymous Problem while calling object property

Tags: c#, linq

I Have this List of objects containing list of objects with tuple
listProducts:

```
[
    [
        {
            "group": "coloris",
            "valeursAndUids": [
                {
                    "Item1": "Beige",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
                },
                {
                    "Item1": "Beige",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
                },
                {
                    "Item1": "Venezia",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
                },
                {
                    "Item1": "Venezia",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "group": "ref_commercial",
            "valeursAndUids": [
                {
                    "Item1": "29245",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
                },
                {
                    "Item1": "29245",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
                },
                {
                    "Item1": "29245",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
                },
                {
                    "Item1": "29245",
                    "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm trying to regroup this list by values

What I have done:

```cs
List<Object> newList = new List<Object>();

foreach (var caracProd in listProducts)
{
    var groupName = caracProd.group;
    var groupValue = caracProd.valeursAndUids;
    var groupedCustomerList = caracProd.valeursAndUids
        .GroupBy(item => item.Item1)
        .Select(group => new { groupName = group.Key, Values = group.Select(item => new { item.Item2 }).ToList() })
        .OrderBy(item => item.groupName);

    newList.Add(groupedCustomerList);
}
```

newList

> [
> [
> {
> "groupName": "Beige",
> "Values": [
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
> }
> ]
> },
> {
> "groupName": "Venezia",
> "Values": [
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
> }
> ]
> }
> ],
> [
> {
> "groupName": "29245",
> "Values": [
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
> }
> ]
> }
> ]  ]

Desired result

> [
> [
> {
> "Coloris": "Beige",
> "Values": [
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
> }
> ]
> },
> {
> "Coloris": "Venezia",
> "Values": [
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
> }
> ]
> }
> ],
> [
> {
> "ref_commercial": "29245",
> "Values": [
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-486274"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-106045"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-205994"
> },
> {
> "Item2": "QB32-20220325-270903"
> }
> ]
> }
> ]  ]

Instead of groupName, I want to get the actual values but i'm having problem to getting the value of the groupName it's returning an anonymous problem.

I tried writing `caracProd.group` unstead of groupName so I can have the value but got an error

[image]

Here's the error I encountered, is there a way to achieve what I want ?

Thank you, So much.

Comment: to reproduce your problem could you display the different classes, you should show the code to build the listProducts  and you are working on json not tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use anonymous types for grouping because in your case their properties' names are determined at runtime.

You could achieve a similar effect by using `Dictionary`:

```cs
var newList = listProducts
    .Select(prod => prod.valeursAndUids
        .GroupBy(item => item.Item1)
        .Select(g =>
        {
            var objAsDict = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { prod.group, g.Key },
                { "Values", g.Select(item => new { item.Item2 }).ToList() }
            };
            return objAsDict;
        })
        .OrderBy(item => item[prod.group]))
    .ToList();
```

or the same with `ExpandoObject`:

```cs
var newList = listProducts
    .Select(prod => prod.valeursAndUids
        .GroupBy(item => item.Item1)
        .Select(g =>
        {
            var d = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
            d.Add(prod.group, g.Key);
            d.Add("Values", g.Select(item => new { item.Item2 }).ToList());
            return d;
        })
        .OrderBy(item => item[prod.group]))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is awesome thank you so much, it's solved my problem.

I'm trying to group by multiple group level : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71682273/groupby-with-multiple-groups-level 

Do you think it's doable with your modification ?? @ruslan-gilmutdinov