# Delete Value from list inside a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I Have this List of objects containing list of objects with tuple
listProducts:  (local variable) `List<((string GroupName, string Valeurs)[] Levels, string[] Uids)>` groupings

```
 [{
    "Item1": [{
        "Item1": "coloris",
        "Item2": "Beige"
    }, {
        "Item1": "ref_commercial",
        "Item2": "29245"
    }],
    "Item2": ["QB32-20220325-486274", "QB32-20220325-106045"]
}, {
    "Item1": [{
        "Item1": "coloris",
        "Item2": "Venezia"
    }, {
        "Item1": "ref_commercial",
        "Item2": "29245"
    }],
    "Item2": ["QB32-20220325-205994", "QB32-20220325-270903"]
}]
```

ListOfIds = `["QB32-20220325-486274", "QB32-20220325-106045", "QB32-20220325-205994", "QB32-20220325-270903"]`

I want to loop through list of ids and check if exist on the listProducts, if so delete it from Item2.

So in the end Item2 will contains an empty list in this case.

Comment: What is `listProducts`? Where is it in your example? BTW, LINQ is for querying - you could create a new modified `List` copy with LINQ, but if you want to modify in place, you should be using `foreach`.

Comment: BTW, why does everyone think JSON is a good way to post C# data? It is really a terrible, terrible way.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `ValueTuple` is a terrible way to store information that needs to be modified (create a class, or if you must, use an anonymous class) and given that C# Arrays should never be used for collections that must be modified (use a `List<T>`), here is some code to replace the elements in the `List<T>` that must be modified:

```
var listOfIds = new[] { "QB32-20220325-486274", "QB32-20220325-106045", "QB32-20220325-205994", "QB32-20220325-270903" }.ToHashSet();

for (int productIndex = 0; productIndex < listProducts.Count; ++productIndex) {
    var product = listProducts[productIndex];
    product.Uids = product.Uids.Where(uid => !listOfIds.Contains(uid)).ToArray();
    listProducts[productIndex] = product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "classical loops" like `for` or `foreach` results in an error `Cannot modify struct member when accessed struct is not classified as a variable`.
This happens because tuples are structs and when accessed inside a `foreach` or `for` you would be ending accessing a copy of this variable, not the variable itself.

But you can use LINQ to do that in a easy way

```
 listProducts = listProducts.Select(x =>
 {
     x.Uids = x.Uids.Except(ListOfIds).ToArray();
     return x;
 }).ToList();
```